# How to use a UIView with a CCLayer cocos2d?

Tags: uiview, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer, ccvideoplayer

I am playing a short video with CCVideoPlayer in cocos2d and at the end of it I am capturing the very last frame of the video and I am showing it on the screen using a UIView because trying to draw it on a CCLayer makes the image show up with slightly different colors. I would imagine that is because the way that things are drawn in cocos2d is different than the way they are drawn on a UIView. So I need some way to keep the image on the screen Using the UIView, and I need to be able to draw sprites etc... on top of this view. So my question is, Is there a way to make a CCLayer transparent so that the UIView containing the image can still be seen and then draw on top of the image using a CCLayer?
(P.S I am using cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b)

Comment: Please provide details about the cocos2d version you are using, since the answer will vary greatly depending on which version you are using.

Comment: I am using cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b